# How to assign list elements to different texts names in python?

Tags: python, direction

I am trying to solve this issue.

I have a list like that:

```
  g = ['hey','man','sup']
```

and i want 3 different text files like "hey.txt","man.txt","sup.txt".

I used;

```
f = open('hey.txt','w')
sys.stdout = f
....
```

but is there a way to do it like that?;

```
for x in range(3):
    f = open('g[x].txt','w')
```

Answer (score 5):

Use string [formatting](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.format):

```
for filename in g:
    f = open('{}.txt'.format(filename),'w')
```

Comment: `for x in g:` would be even better... especially if you replaced `x` with `filename` to get expressive variable names.

Answer (score 5):

you are almost there

Instead of this

```
for x in range(3):
    f = open('g[x].txt','w')
```

Do this:

```
for x in range(3):
    f = open(g[x]+'.txt','w')
```

The actual problem is `'g[x].txt'` it is a string and it's value does not change during each iteration where as to get `g` elements we use g[x] which return a string which then can be appended with `'.txt'` to form the file name

You could use [`context manager to open the file object`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3693771/trying-to-understand-python-with-statement-and-context-managers)

**i.e)**

```
for x in range(3):
    with open(g[x]+'.txt','w') as f:
```

If you want both index and value then you could use [**enumerator**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22171558/what-does-enumerate-mean)

**i.e.)**

```
for index,value in enumerate(g):
    with open(value+'.txt','w') as f:
```

Comment: You could also iterate the _iterable_ directly: ` for value in g:`

Comment: @wap26 yes we could :)