# Random connection errors with aio_pika after 2 days of running

Tags: python-3.x, python-asyncio, pika, aio

I have asyncio script which connects to rabbitmq with aio_pika library every 40 seconds and checks if there are any messages and prints them out which then repeats forever. However, usually, after 2 or so days of running, I will start receiving endless connection exception errors which will only be solved by restarting the script. Perhaps there are some obvious mistakes in the logic of my asyncio script which I am missing?

```py
#!/usr/bin/python3
import time
import async_timeout
import asyncio
import aio_pika

async def got_message(message: aio_pika.IncomingMessage):
    with message.process():
        print(message.body.decode())

async def main(loop):
    try:
        with async_timeout.timeout(10):
            connection = await aio_pika.connect_robust(
                host='#', 
                virtualhost='#', 
                login='#', 
                password='#',
                port=5671,
                loop=loop, 
                ssl=True
            )

            channel = await connection.channel()

            await channel.set_qos(prefetch_count=100)

            queue_name='mm_message'
            queue = await channel.declare_queue(auto_delete=False, name=queue_name)

            routing_key='mm_msg'
            await queue.bind("amq.topic", routing_key)
            que_len = queue.declaration_result.message_count
            if(que_len > 0):
                await queue.consume(got_message)
    except:
        print("connection problems..")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    while(True):
        time.sleep(40)
        loop.run_until_complete(main(loop))
```

This is the error I endlessly receive after some time:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/asyncio/events.py", line 125, in _run
    self._callback(*self._args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/aio_pika/pika/adapters/base_connection.py", line 364, in _handle_events
    self._handle_read()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/aio_pika/pika/adapters/base_connection.py", line 415, in _handle_read
    self._on_data_available(data)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/aio_pika/pika/connection.py", line 1347, in _on_data_available
    self._process_frame(frame_value)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/aio_pika/pika/connection.py", line 1414, in _process_frame
    if self._process_callbacks(frame_value):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/aio_pika/pika/connection.py", line 1384, in _process_callbacks
    frame_value)  # Args
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/aio_pika/pika/callback.py", line 60, in wrapper
    return function(*tuple(args), **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/aio_pika/pika/callback.py", line 92, in wrapper
    return function(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/aio_pika/pika/callback.py", line 236, in process
    callback(*args, **keywords)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/aio_pika/pika/connection.py", line 1332, in _on_connection_tune
    self._send_connection_open()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/aio_pika/pika/connection.py", line 1517, in _send_connection_open
    self._on_connection_open, [spec.Connection.OpenOk])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/aio_pika/pika/connection.py", line 1501, in _rpc
    self._send_method(channel_number, method_frame)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/aio_pika/pika/connection.py", line 1569, in _send_method
    self._send_frame(frame.Method(channel_number, method_frame))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/aio_pika/pika/connection.py", line 1548, in _send_frame
    raise exceptions.ConnectionClosed
aio_pika.pika.exceptions.ConnectionClosed
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
except:
    print("connection problems..")
```

This will catch service Exceptions like `KeyboardInterrupt`, `SystemExit`. You should [never do](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21553825/1113207) such thing if you're not going to reraise exception. At very lest you should write:

```
except Exception:
    print("connection problems..")
```

However in context of `asyncio` snippet above will break mechanism of [cancellation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.Task.cancel). To avoid it as explained [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-exceptions.html#asyncio.CancelledError) you should write:

```
try:
    await operation
except asyncio.CancelledError:
    raise
except Exception:
    log.log('an error has occurred')
```

---

Not less important is to understand that connection should not only be opened, but closed also (regardless of what happened between opening and closing). To achieve that people usually use [context managers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36559849/1113207) (and in `asyncio` - asynchronous context managers).

`aio_pika` doesn't seem to be exception. As [example](https://github.com/mosquito/aio-pika#usage-example) shows you should use `async with` when dealing with connection:

```
connection = await aio_pika.connect_robust(
    "amqp://guest:guest@127.0.0.1/", loop=loop
)

async with connection:
    # ...
```

Comment: Should try...except be used with every await operation? Thanks for your input, this is really helpful.

Comment: @A.Smith no, it shouldn't. What I'm saying is: any awaitable can potentially raise `CancelledError` and you shouldn't prevent it to be propagated unless you the one who explicitly cancelled this awaitable.