# What is the best way to multiprocess for loops?

Tags: python, for-loop, multiprocessing

I am learning the basics of multiprocessing and want to divide for loops into seperate processes to be processed on different cpu cores. I am planning to implement multiprocessing in an existing script, that does heavy computation.

Right now my approach looks like this:

```
import multiprocessing as mp
from functools import partial

def function(a, b, numbers):
    return a*b

if __name__ == '__main__':
    a = 1
    b = 2
    numbers = range(1000)
    func_part = partial(function, a, b)
    # Pool function
    result = mp.Pool().map(func_part, numbers)
    print(result)

    # equivalent for loop
    L = []
    for i in numbers:
        L.append(function(a, b, i))
    print(L)
```

1. Is there a better approach in doing this?
2. Is it possible to get the iterator `numbers` as first parameter of the `function` without breaking it? `numbers` has to be passed lastly by the `map` function it seems.

Comment: How do you define "better"?

Comment: Efficiency and syntax simplicity?

Comment: IMO that's too vague.

Comment: How about `more pythonic`?

Comment: @ArturMüllerRomanov if you look in the docs [here](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/multiprocessing.html#module-multiprocessing.pool) you will see an example of  how to use `multiprocessing.Pool`, in the example the context manager it is used, I guess this can be considered a pythonic example

Comment: @kederrac's suggestion of using the `Pool` as context manager fits that description. If you don't care about order, using `map_sync()` might be more efficient in the sense of allowing more concurrent processing to take place (since the processes don't depend on each other).

Comment: @martineau Doesn't `map_async()` respect the order, just like `map()`? I believe `imap_unordered()` is the method to use if you don't care about the order.

Answer (score 1):

you can use a context manager:

```
with mp.Pool() as p:
    print(p.map(func_part, numbers))
```

---

> Is it possible to get the iterator numbers as first parameter of the
>   function without breaking it?

yes, it is possible, but you are not passing the iterator to the function, you are passing an item from your `numabers` variable

```
def function(number, a, b, ):
    return a*b

a = 1
b = 2
numbers = range(1000)
func_part = partial(function, a=a, b=b)



with mp.Pool() as p:
    print(p.map(func_part, numbers))
```

Comment: what are the benefits of using one?

Comment: you may have a look of why to use a context manger : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36559580/what-is-the-purpose-of-a-context-manager-in-python