# Does the 'with' keyword close the connection if there is error in my SQL?

Tags: python, with-statement

I have trouble with a database connection. I have a script that executes  another script (below) 2000 times.
I'm using pg database. I have set the limit number of connection to 5 maximum. But it look like there is more than 5 connections at same time because my cpu is running at 100% and in stats of my database that say I have more than 100 connections in same time.

**So I'm wondering if the keyword "with" closes the connection if there is an error in my SQL?**

Here my code that is executed 2000 times by another script:

```
try:
    engine = create_database_connection()
    with engine.connect() as connection:
        groups_sql = connection.execute(
            text('SELECT uuid, name FROM user_group WHERE project_id = :project_id'),
            project_id=project['uuid']
        ).fetchall()
except:
  print('error')
```

Comment: Yes that's what it's for. See [Explaining Python's '__enter__' and '__exit__'](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44387478/202229) or [What is the purpose of a context manager in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36559580/what-is-the-purpose-of-a-context-manager-in-python)

Comment: Moreover it will close the connection when it finishes without error too.

Comment: What library are you using here? We all know what a context manager is, but I do not know what does `create_database_connection` **before** the `with` block. Furthemore, opening a dabase connection per query is **very** resource consuming.

Comment: ok thank you that answer the question

Comment: Generally you open a database connection(s) for a session, not just an individual query. Like @SergeBallesta said.