# Why not assign a variable instead of using `with .. as`?

Tags: python, sockets, python-sockets

I'm learning socket programming in Python, and saw that a person used this piece of code:

```
with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as s:
    s.bind((HOST, PORT))
    s.listen()
    conn, addr = s.accept()
```

Why would you use `with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as s` instead of `s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)`? Is there any difference between these which makes one better to use in this case?

Comment: `with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as s:` is a context manger. If something unexpected like an error happens, it is designed to clean up the `socket` object (call `s.close()`, etc.) so you don't have to worry about it yourself.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the purpose of a context manager in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36559580/what-is-the-purpose-of-a-context-manager-in-python)

Comment: The `with` statement is a kind of assignment statement, but it's not (directly) assigning the socket to `s`; it's assigning the return value of the socket's `__enter__` method to `s`.