# byte to sequence of 8 bits conversion in Python

Tags: python, binary

I am learning working with binary files in Python. If I read one byte at a time, how can I convert it into a sequence of 8 bits? (stored in a datatype list for example).

My objective is to work with individual bits, however I have read that in Python one can only read bytes from a binary file. So I am asking how to do the conversion.

Thank you.

Here is my code of reading a byte:

```
f1=open("filename.jpg","rb")

for x in f1:
    t=f1.read(1)
    

f1.close()
```

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/699866/python-int-to-binary-string) answer your question? Also, you should use a [context manager](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36559849/16177247), instead of `open()` and `f1.close()`

Comment: Yes. It helped. Thank you.