# If you os.open() and open() a file, you need to both close() and os.close() it?

Tags: python, linux, file

I'm opening a file in Python using `os.open()`, and then I want to write to it using the file interface, ie. `f.write()`.

So I'm doing the following

```
import os

fd = os.open('log', os.O_CREAT|os.O_RDWR, 0b111110110)
f  = open(fd,'w')
```

But when it's time to clean up, I don't know if I should do call both `os.close(fd)` and `f.close()`, or only one.

Calling `os.close()` xor `f.close()` is fine (ie. exactly one), but calling both throws a "bad file descriptor" error.

Comment: Why are you using `os.open` and not the built-in [`open`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open)? See the [Reading and Writing Files](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files) tutorial.

Comment: Yes, you need to close it. But you can use the "with" statement and it will close automatically. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36559580/what-is-the-purpose-of-a-context-manager-in-python/36559849#:~:text=Context%20managers%20are%20a%20way,%3E%20foo%2C%20%22Hello!%22

Comment: Can you clarify what you are asking? The question already mentions that it's not possible to "call both ``os.close(fd)`` and ``f.close()``" so obviously you have to call "only one". Are you wondering *which* one to call?

Comment: This can easily be found out from reading the documentation. https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open -- "If a file descriptor is given, it is closed when the returned I/O object is closed unless closefd is set to False".

Comment: @MisterMiyagi yes, exactly

Comment: @Dunes That's exactly the type of answer I was looking for. Thank you. I was lazy and didn't even bother going over the docs, though I'll admit I didn't think they'd even mention it. I was wrong.