# How to clean up connections after KeyboardInterrupt in python-trio

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.5, python-3.6, python-trio

My class when is connected to the server should immediately send *sign in* string, afterwards when the session is over it should send out the *sign out* string and clean up the sockets. Below is my code.

```
import trio

class test:

    _buffer = 8192
    _max_retry = 4

    def __init__(self, host='127.0.0.1', port=12345, usr='user', pwd='secret'):
        self.host = str(host)
        self.port = int(port)
        self.usr = str(usr)
        self.pwd = str(pwd)
        self._nl = b'\r\n'
        self._attempt = 0
        self._queue = trio.Queue(30)
        self._connected = trio.Event()
        self._end_session = trio.Event()

    @property
    def connected(self):
        return self._connected.is_set()

    async def _sender(self, client_stream, nursery):
        print('## sender: started!')
        q = self._queue
        while True:
            cmd = await q.get()
            print('## sending to the server:\n{!r}\n'.format(cmd))
            if self._end_session.is_set():
                nursery.cancel_scope.shield = True
                with trio.move_on_after(1):
                    await client_stream.send_all(cmd)
                nursery.cancel_scope.shield = False
            await client_stream.send_all(cmd)

    async def _receiver(self, client_stream, nursery):
        print('## receiver: started!')
        buff = self._buffer
        while True:
            data = await client_stream.receive_some(buff)
            if not data:
                print('## receiver: connection closed')
                self._end_session.set()
                break
            print('## got data from the server:\n{!r}'.format(data))

    async def _watchdog(self, nursery):
        await self._end_session.wait()
        await self._queue.put(self._logoff)
        self._connected.clear()
        nursery.cancel_scope.cancel()

    @property
    def _login(self, *a, **kw):
        nl = self._nl
        usr, pwd = self.usr, self.pwd
        return nl.join(x.encode() for x in ['Login', usr,pwd]) + 2*nl

    @property
    def _logoff(self, *a, **kw):
        nl = self._nl
        return nl.join(x.encode() for x in ['Logoff']) + 2*nl

    async def _connect(self):
        host, port = self.host, self.port
        print('## connecting to {}:{}'.format(host, port))
        try:
            client_stream = await trio.open_tcp_stream(host, port)
        except OSError as err:
            print('##', err)
        else:
            async with client_stream:
                self._end_session.clear()
                self._connected.set()
                self._attempt = 0
                # Sign in as soon as connected
                await self._queue.put(self._login)
                async with trio.open_nursery() as nursery:
                    print("## spawning watchdog...")
                    nursery.start_soon(self._watchdog, nursery)
                    print("## spawning sender...")
                    nursery.start_soon(self._sender, client_stream, nursery)
                    print("## spawning receiver...")
                    nursery.start_soon(self._receiver, client_stream, nursery)

    def connect(self):
        while self._attempt <= self._max_retry:
            try:
                trio.run(self._connect)
                trio.run(trio.sleep, 1)
                self._attempt += 1
            except KeyboardInterrupt:
                self._end_session.set()
                print('Bye bye...')
                break

tst = test()
tst.connect()
```

My logic doesn't quite work. Well it works if I kill the `netcat` listener, so then my session looks like the following:

```
## connecting to 127.0.0.1:12345
## spawning watchdog...
## spawning sender...
## spawning receiver...
## receiver: started!
## sender: started!
## sending to the server:
b'Login\r\nuser\r\nsecret\r\n\r\n'

## receiver: connection closed
## sending to the server:
b'Logoff\r\n\r\n'
```

Note that `Logoff` string has been sent out, although it doesn't make sense in here as connection is already broken by that time.

However my goal is to `Logoff` when user `KeyboardInterrupt`. In this case my session looks similar to this:

```
## connecting to 127.0.0.1:12345
## spawning watchdog...
## spawning sender...
## spawning receiver...
## receiver: started!
## sender: started!
## sending to the server:
b'Login\r\nuser\r\nsecret\r\n\r\n'

Bye bye...
```

Note that `Logoff` hasn't been sent off.

Any ideas?

Comment: Sounds like a classic use for a context manager.  You'll probably want an [asynchronous context manager](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0492/#asynchronous-context-managers-and-async-with).  It looks like a decorator a la `contextlib.contextmanager` might be in 3.7, but there isn't a stable release of that yet. You might also want to look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37433157/asynchronous-context-manager).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here your call tree looks something like:

```
connect
|
+- _connect*
   |
   +- _watchdog*
   |
   +- _sender*
   |
   +- _receiver*
```

The `*`s indicate the 4 trio tasks. The `_connect` task is sitting at the end of the nursery block, waiting for the child tasks to complete. The `_watchdog` task is blocked in `await self._end_session.wait()`, the `_sender` task is blocked in `await q.get()`, and the `_receiver` task is blocked in `await client_stream.receive_some(...)`.

When you hit control-C, then the standard Python semantics are that whatever bit of Python code is running suddenly raises `KeyboardInterrupt`. In this case, you have 4 different tasks running, so one of those blocked operations gets picked at random [1], and raises a `KeyboardInterrupt`. This means a few different things might happen:

- If `_watchdog`'s `wait` call raises `KeyboardInterrupt`, then the `_watchdog` method immediately exits, so it never even tries to send `logout`. Then as part of unwinding the stack, trio cancels all the other tasks, and once they've exited then the `KeyboardInterrupt` keeps propagating up until it reaches your `finally` block in `connect`. At this point you try to notify the watchdog task using `self._end_session.set()`, but it's not running anymore, so it doesn't notice.
- If `_sender`'s `q.get()` call raises `KeyboardInterrupt`, then the `_sender` method immediately exits, so even if the `_watchdog` did ask it to send a logoff message, it won't be there to notice. And in any case, trio then proceeds to cancel the watchdog and receiver tasks anyway, and things proceed as above.
- If `_receiver`'s `receive_all` call raises `KeyboardInterrupt`... same thing happens.
- Minor subtlety: `_connect` can also receive the `KeyboardInterrupt`, which does the same thing: cancels all the children, and then waits for them to stop before allowing the `KeyboardInterrupt` to keep propagating.

If you want to reliably catch control-C and then do something with it, then this business of it being raised at some random point is quite a nuisance. The simplest way to do this is to use [Trio's support for catching signals](https://trio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference-io.html#signals) to catch the `signal.SIGINT` signal, which is the thing that Python normally converts into a `KeyboardInterrupt`. (The "INT" stands for "interrupt".) Something like:

```
async def _control_c_watcher(self):
    # This API is currently a little cumbersome, sorry, see
    # https://github.com/python-trio/trio/issues/354
    with trio.catch_signals({signal.SIGINT}) as batched_signal_aiter:
        async for _ in batched_signal_aiter:
            self._end_session.set()
            # We exit the loop, restoring the normal behavior of
            # control-C. This way hitting control-C once will try to
            # do a polite shutdown, but if that gets stuck the user
            # can hit control-C again to raise KeyboardInterrupt and
            # force things to exit.
            break
```

and then start this running alongside your other tasks.

You also have the problem that in your `_watchdog` method, it puts the `logoff` request into the queue – thus scheduling a message to be sent later, by the `_sender` task – and then immediately cancels all the tasks, so that the `_sender` task probably won't get a chance to see the message and react to it! In general, I find my code works nicer when I use tasks only when necessary. Instead of having a sender task and then putting messages in a queue when you want to send them, why not have the code that wants to send a message call `stream.send_all` directly? The one thing you have to watch out for is if you have multiple tasks that might send things simultaneously, you might want to use a `trio.Lock()` to make sure they don't bump into each other by calling `send_all` at the same time:

```
async def send_all(self, data):
    async with self.send_lock:
        await self.send_stream.send_all(data)

async def do_logoff(self):
    # First send the message
    await self.send_all(b"Logoff\r\n\r\n")
    # And then, *after* the message has been sent, cancel the tasks
    self.nursery.cancel()
```

If you do it this way, you might be able to get rid of the watchdog task and the `_end_session` event entirely.

A few other notes about your code while I'm here:

- Calling `trio.run` multiple times like this is unusual. The normal style is to call it once at the top of your program, and put all your real code inside it. Once you exit `trio.run`, all of trio's state is lost, you're definitely not running any concurrent tasks (so there's no way anything could *possibly* be listening and notice your call to `_end_session.set()`!). And in general, almost all Trio functions assume that you're already inside a call to `trio.run`. It turns out that right now you can call `trio.Queue()` before starting trio without getting an exception, but that's basically just a coincidence.
- The use of shielding inside `_sender` looks odd to me. Shielding is generally an advanced feature that you *almost never* want to use, and I don't think this is an exception.

Hope that helps! And if you want to talk more about style/design issues like this but are worried they might be too vague for stack overflow ("is this program designed well?"), then feel free to drop by the [trio chat channel](https://gitter.im/python-trio/general).

---

[1] Well, actually trio probably picks the main task for various reasons, but that's not guaranteed and in any case it doesn't make a difference here.

Comment: Thanks, that explains a lot. I've implemented other `thread` only class, where `sender` and `receiver` run in the separate threads. Using similar `Event.set()` and `Event.wait()` choreography I can send the final `Logoff` no problem, as `KeyboardInterrupt` affects only the master thread, but not its children. Given that I do not seek massive concurrency but rather run a few tasks in parallel, I suppose I would be better if I stick to threads, rather than try to catch random exceptions in each `coroutine`?

Comment: Regarding `trio.run(trio.sleep, 1)`, I know it's a sign of bad style or perhaps gargantuan laziness, but I needed something to "sleep" in there and was reluctant to scroll all the way up and import `time.sleep`. It's there *not because* I've tried to insert `checkpoint` or do something concurrently.

Comment: @NarūnasK My `_control_c_watcher` example shows you how to make sure that control-C is always delivered to a single task, so it acts similar to the threads case. Threads also create a lot of other challenges, so I wouldn't choose just based on control-C handling, but of course you should use whatever works for you. One thing to consider though: there's no way to cancel a thread, so how are you going to wake up the receive thread when you want to exit?

Comment: And regarding the multiple calls to `trio.run`: I wasn't responding to the sleep in particular. Even without that, it's already unusual to be calling `trio.run` multiple times in a loop, and it's not supported to be creating trio objects or calling `trio.Event.set` from outside a call to `trio.run`. I'm suggesting you write `async def main(): tst = test(); await tst.connect()` and then do `trio.run(main)` as the very first call when your program starts executing.