# How can I fix a RuntimeWarning using the 'atexit' module?

Tags: discord, discord.py, bots, atexit

Recently, I've been wanting to create an exit handler for my discord bot which sends an embed every time it goes offline.
I found out through some quick research about the `atexit` module.
I tried to incorporate it in my code like so:

```
import atexit
# Also other imports which make discord.py and interactions work...

def my_exit_handler():
    print("Exiting the program")
    time = get_current_timestamp() # this works
    embed = discord.Embed(
        title=" ",
        description=f"##  Bot is Restarting. Time now: <t:{time}> (<t:{time}:R>)",
        color=0x005300  # Green color
    )
    channel_id = 1149359551464882229
    final = bot.get_channel(channel_id)
    final.send(embed=embed)
    save_thread_data() # For other parts of my code
    save_leaderboard_data() # For other parts of my code

# ALL OF MY MAIN.PY CODE..

atexit.register(my_exit_handler)

bot.run('my token')
```

however, any time I try to make it work, these errors pop up:

```
/home/container/main.py:186: RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'Messageable.send' was never awaited
  final.send(embed=embed)
RuntimeWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback
```

How can I fix them?

I'm expecting to see an embed pop up at that ID adress with the embed I asked.

I also tried making it into an async def but that brough up a whole other set of problems.

Answer (score 0):

[Messageable.send](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.abc.Messageable.send) is an asynchronous functions; asynchronous functions need to be awaited with the await keyword.

```
await final.send(embed=embed)
```

For more: [awaitables](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#awaitables).

This also means that the `my_exit_handler` function also has to be asynchronous.

```
async def my_exit_handler():
    ...
```

Comment: Okay but where should I place `await atexit.register(my_exit_handler)` ?
Before it was without the 'await' as it was a normal def, but now that its an async I have no clue where to place this, as I can't place it at the end of my code as `await` is outside of function, and in on_ready(): gives me errors..

Comment: Since you’re inputting the function and not calling it, you should place it without the `await` and without the parentheses

Comment: could you please clarify, as im still unclear because my_exit_handler() is an async therefore it will never work without an `await` block, and infact its telling me that my_exit_handler() was never awaited. If I do not plae the parenthesis, nothing happens. When I place it like this: `await atexit.register(my_exit_handler)` it gives me the `await out of function` error, but when i do not put the await, it tells me `sys:1: RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'my_exit_handler' was never awaited`

Comment: This is an oversight due to my lack of knowledge on the library. For your question, `atexit.register` takes in a function, so you parse it without parentheses, without await because you're not calling the function just yet. However, `atexit` isn't normally used with asynchronous functions, you might want to look into [asyncio-atexit](https://pypi.org/project/asyncio-atexit/)

Comment: Or you can try [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53640988/is-there-a-way-to-run-an-asyncio-coroutine-using-atexit).