# Tensorflow: tf.name_scope without 'with'

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow, deep-learning

I would like to use `tf.name_scope` for something like this:

```
my_scope = tf.name_scope('something')

if cond_1:
    foo(my_scope)

if cond_2:
    bar(my_scope)
```

I would like to avoid using the `with tf.name_scope('something') as scope` notation, as I don't know when the first time I want to use the name scope `something`.
The simple `my_scope = tf.name_scope('something')` doesn't work, resulting in the error `TypeError: expected string or buffer`.

Right now I use:

```
with tf.name_scope('something') as scope:
    pass
my_scope = scope

if cond_1:
    foo(my_scope)

if cond_2:
    bar(my_scope)
```

which works, but is very unsatisfying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure what `foo` and `bar` are supposed to do, but two `my_scope` in the provided above snippets are completely different.

The first `my_scope` is a [context manager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3693771/trying-to-understand-python-with-statement-and-context-managers), namely `contextlib.GeneratorContextManager` instance. The second `my_scope` (just as `scope`) is an ordinary string, namely `"something/"` (see the [source code](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py#L3615)). You can achieve exactly the same effect with just `my_scope="something/"`. Based on the error *TypeError: expected string or buffer*, that's exactly what `foo` and `bar` expect - a string.

Also note that you can get a reference on a context and enter it whenever you like. `tf.name_scope` simply pushes the name on top of the stack and then pops it back on exit. But if you enter the same name scope multiple times, you'll get a suffix: `_1`, `_2`, ...