# How to refactor `with` statement in Python to use pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, loops, with-statement

I'm trying to refactor the following pseudo-code logic to take the function from reading and writing to files to be all in memory using pandas, but am confused by how the `with` function operates as compared to a loop over a `pandas` `dataframe`.

This is the code I would like to refactor:

```
results = []
with open('data.csv', 'rt') as ins:
    next(ins)  # drop header
    a1, b1, c1 = next(ins).strip().split(',')
    for i, line in enumerate(ins, 2):
        a2, b1, c1 = line.strip().split(',')
        ...
        results.append(dummy_func(a1 b1, c1))
    else:
        results.append(dummy_func(a1 b1, c1))
```

Is this the in memory equivalent, in particular I'm not sure if `with` `ins` are lines in the file, do I need both `itertuples`, and on a side note is `itertuples` the best thing to use here, faster than `iterrows` for example?

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('data.csv', sep=',')
results = []
for row in df.itertuples():
    a1, b1, c1 = row.a, row.b, row.c
    for row2 in df.loc[2:].itertuples():
        a1, b1, c1 = row2.a, row2.b, row2.c
        ...
        result.append(dummy_func(a1, b1, c1))
    else: 
        result.append(dummy_func(a1, b1, c1))
```

Comment: `with...` is a context manager for opening the file. Pandas `read_csv` has built-in file context management, so there's no need to use `with`. Beyond that, it's nearly impossible to say what the best way to achieve your goal is, because you haven't described it. In general, there are few reasons you should ever need to iterate over a pandas dataframe, but that's entirely context dependent. Please see [How to creat good pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) and provide some sample input and output for better help

Comment: @G.Anderson thanks very much, please could you help me to understand what that means that `read_csv` has built in file context management, or point me to somewhere for more information on that?

Comment: Why are you replacing your efficient version with an inefficient pandas version? Just use the `csv` module.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3693771/trying-to-understand-python-with-statement-and-context-managers

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga this is part of a pipeline and I don't want to keep reading and writing intermediate files

Comment: @WilliamGrimes you wouldn't have to, any more than you would with pandas. In any case, both `itertuples` and `iterrows` will be slow compared to a `csv` based  solution. And less memory efficient (significantly so)

Answer (score 0):

Okay I misunderstood the `with` statement this is the answer

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('data.csv', sep=',')
results = []
a1, b1, c1 = row.a, row.b, row.c
for row2 in df.loc[1:].itertuples():
    a1, b1, c1 = row2.a, row2.b, row2.c
    ...
    result.append(dummy_func(a1, b1, c1))
else: 
    result.append(dummy_func(a1, b1, c1))
```